# Firefox not providing search suggestions with DuckDuckGo

Tags: 14.04, firefox

When I type in the search bar no suggestions appear when DuckDuckGo is the default search engine, but if I switch to Google, it works fine. I would like to use DuckDuckGo as my default search engine but I like having search suggestions. I have been in the preferences and made sure the "Provide search suggestions" box is checked. I'm using Firefox 38.0 and Ubuntu 14.04. Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: I confirmed the same problem, though it works OK on Windows. All I could suggest would be open the main DuckDuckGo search page in a tab. The old DuckDuckGo search addon from before it was integrated acts the same way.

Comment: The same problem can be found in Ubuntu 15.10 with Firefox 42. Did you find a solution for the problem?

Comment: I haven't found any solution as of yet.

Answer (score 1):

The answer lies in the nature of DuckDuckGo itself. Since the search engine doesn't track users or store their search history, it doesn't provide a search suggestion service. If you really need that, stick to Google.